# JavaFX draw line alignment with slider

Tags: java, video, javafx, slider

I'm using JavaFx MediaPlayer to play video files which have slider as a timeline. I want to draw line alignment with the point which is clicked any point on timeline. For that I've used the below code:

**In FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<VBox prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                     <children>
                        <Slider fx:id="timeSlider" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
                        <Group fx:id="group" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
```

**In FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
timeSlider.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                StackPane p = (StackPane)timeSlider.lookup(".thumb");
                double x = p.getLayoutX() +( p.getWidth() /2);
                Line line = new Line(x,0,x,100);
                line.setFill(Color.RED);
                line.setStroke(Color.RED);
                line.getStyleClass().clear();
                line.getStyleClass().add("multi_graph_scribe");
                group.getChildren().add(line);

                if(!line.isVisible())
                    line.setVisible(true);
            });
```

But the line does not draw in correct position with slider thumb.Could any one help me to resolve the above issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it draw at all, and what position related to the thumb does it draw? i.e. 6 pixels right every time.

Comment: Instead of `getLayoutX()` try using `getLayoutBounds().getMinX()`. MinX is the upper left corner of the geometric bounds of the `StackPane`, which sounds like thats what you are trying to use.

Comment: It always draws left of thumb

Comment: Thanks  @Hypnic Jerk  I tried getLayoutBounds().getMinX() also, but it does not work it draws left of the thumb also

Comment: @Hypnic Jerk I tried getBoundsInParent() in the posted question but it does not work also

Comment: I just attempted to recreate the issue and I indeed can. It seems to be a problem with `Group`, and not necessarily any calculations you are doing. I was adding 1000 to the `x` and it still showed up on the left side everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two things I've found that is throwing you off.

First, `Group` isn't working the way you and I expected it to work, for some reason it always put the `Line` to the left of the thumb.

Second, the `x` being calculated looks like it should work but it doesn't. During my tests using the `getWidth()/2` is about 5 off of using the method I used., but I'll show the updated code below

So to fix the first problem, I switched out `Group` for `Pane`. This will still allow you to put items `(x,y)` wherever you need.

To fix the positioning problem, I changed the expression to

```
double x = p.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + ((p.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX()-p.getBoundsInParent().getMinX())/2);
```

Which, as you can see, didn't use the thumb's width, but instead used its bounded width, which were different.

This resulted in the below code.

```
timeSlider.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    StackPane p = (StackPane)timeSlider.lookup(".thumb");
    System.out.println(p.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + " " + p.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX() + " " + p.getWidth());
    double x = p.getBoundsInParent().getMinX() + ((p.getBoundsInParent().getMaxX()-p.getBoundsInParent().getMinX())/2);
    System.out.println(x);
    Line line = new Line(x,0,x,100);
    line.setFill(Color.RED);
    line.setStroke(Color.RED);
    line.getStyleClass().clear();
    group.getChildren().add(line);
    System.out.println(line.getBoundsInParent());

    if(!line.isVisible())
        line.setVisible(true);
});

<VBox prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <children>
        <Slider fx:id="timeSlider" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
        <Pane fx:id="group" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Hope this helps.